# Unable to open Android layout xml file in Graphical layout using ADT eclipse

Tags: android, xml, layout, adt

I am Android Developer. I don't know what happen to my eclipse packages, i`m not able open my XML layouts in 'graphical layout'.

I tried different scenarios like clean the project, restart the eclipse and tried to create new workspaces. Tried with different sdk`s 19, 18,17 but still i am facing same issue.

I have attached the screenshot. Any help from android developers will be appreciated.

[image]

Adding full stack for the exception.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x1110014.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getBoolean(BridgeResources.java:461)
    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.<init>(ViewConfiguration.java:308)
    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:330)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3439)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:459)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:168)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:294)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:451)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:718)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationChooser.onRenderingTargetChange(ConfigurationChooser.java:1652)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.TargetMenuListener.widgetSelected(TargetMenuListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1458)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3982)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3621)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Adding XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well... The error is right there, read the text in the yellow box. You have a resource in your xml that cannot be retrieved. So go to the `xml-View and find the line that declares the missing resource. Then change it or delete it

Comment: Avalancha, 
Those xml reference are from themes.xml. I tired to delete those files from sdk res files. But still it is occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the target api of your project. Set it to below than Api level 19 and also change the api from bar displaying above layout(Graphically). And also change the theme of your project in styles.xml to android:Theme.Holo.Light, if you have any other theme mentioned in in style.xml Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `version 19` to lower version in top right side of the layout.(Currently it is selected 19 as seen in Image).

Comment: where you change it? in Manifest file or in xml editor window

Comment: Could you post your xml file here?

Comment: The following usually help:

Clean your project (again, just in case).
Restart eclipse.
Refresh your folders in eclipse (right click -> refresh, or select your top folder and press f5).

Comment: Edited my question and posted xml and exception stack. Can you please have a look.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49560/discussion-between-nagendra-and-renjith-krishnan)

Comment: Hey Renjith, I resolved my issue by installing new bundle SDK on my machine. May be it was missing some xml files.